# For-Loop printing entire range

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I'm new to Python and learning about For Loops and wrote this code:

```
cars = [1, 2, 3, 4]
trucks = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'white']

for numbers in cars:
    print (f"I can count: {numbers}")

for colors in trucks:
    print(f"I can list colors: {colors}")

new_list = []

for numbers in range(0, 4):
    new_list.append(numbers)

for numbers in new_list:
    print(f"I can count more: {new_list}!")
```

and I'm getting this result:

```
I can count: 1
I can count: 2
I can count: 3
I can count: 4
I can list colors: red
I can list colors: blue
I can list colors: green
I can list colors: white
I can count more: [0, 1, 2, 3]!
I can count more: [0, 1, 2, 3]!
I can count more: [0, 1, 2, 3]!
I can count more: [0, 1, 2, 3]!
```

For the "I can count more" part, how do I get it to list the range in numeric order:

```
I can count more: 1! 
I can count more: 2!, etc.
```

instead of printing the entire range in the line?

Comment: Pass it {numbers} instead of {new_list}?

Comment: You could also simplify creating `new_list` as `new_list = range(4)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
print(f"I can count more: {new_list}!")
```

should be

```
print(f"I can count more: {numbers}!")
```

since `new_list` is the entire list and `numbers` is your `for` variable defined in `for numbers in new_list`

Comment: It should also be `number` instead of `numbers`. Otherwise every pedants in the world will complain :-)

Comment: I'm just following the question variable names @paxdiablo

Answer (score 0):

Use "numbers" instead of "new_list". And do not iterate again and again over the same list as new_list contains the same items you are showing in the last loop. So,your code should be like this,

```
for numbers in range(0, 4):
    print(f"I can count more: {numbers}!")
```